# React-player using the dashjs player extend to modify the header field does not take effect

Tags: react-player

When using react-player to play MPEG-DASH streaming media files, each streaming media file needs to be encrypted and played. It is necessary to add a header field or add a parameter to the URL to facilitate verification. I use dashjs to play device, and did the corresponding operation, but it didn’t work, please see the demo for details

Environment

Browser: Chrome Version 115.0.5762.4 (Official Build) dev (arm64)

Operating system: M1

example: https://codesandbox.io/s/black-mountain-ds3iol?file=/src/App.js